# (.bmenu:hover li a) VS (.bmenu li a:hover) - difference?

Tags: css, hover

I would like to ask anyone who could help me where is the difference between this two CSS tags.

```
.bmenu:hover li a{...}
```

VS

```
.bmenu li a:hover{...}
```

Thank you very much for help and sry for my bad english.

Edit 1: I would like to ask for explanation mainly, how do they both work, because in the first case, there is a "li a" behind the :hover. What does it mean please? Thx

Answer (score 0):

To explain this, I'll use this example code:

```
<div class="bmenu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">one</a></li>
<li><a href="#">two</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

if you use `.bmenu:hover` you're saying you want the CSS to apply when you hover the **ENTIRE** `.bmenu` div.

When you say `.bmenu li a:hover` you are saying that you want to apply the CSS when you hover the `a` tag within a `.bmenu` `li`.

Here's a quick example I made, the top is using the `.bmenu:hover` method, and the bottom is using the `li a:hover` method. [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sa51gh27/).

Comment: ok, thank you, but why is "li a" after the :hover tag (in my first example)? What does it mean for functionality? Thx

Comment: in the first `.bmenu:hover li a` you are basically saying *"When I hover `.bmenu` I want the style of my `a` within the `li` to do this."* So in my example I am saying, *When I hover `.bmenu` I want my `a` that is within the `li` tag to change color to white and background to yellow.* As opposed to the second one saying that I want the change to occur ONLY when I hover the `a`.

Comment: Ok, finally big THX, I think I've understood it at last.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help! Just think of it as anytime `:hover` is after something, that's what you need to hover to make the effect take place. Any elements called after it, are going to be what is changed.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case an `<a>` will apply styles when you hover `.bmenu`, in the second case - when you hover the `<a>` itself. Take a look at these two blocks:

```css
.bmenu1, .bmenu2 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 40px;
    background-color: orange;
}
a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: firebrick;
}
.bmenu1:hover a {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.bmenu2 a:hover {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="bmenu1">
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
<div class="bmenu2">
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```